# Spanish Glossary

Tags: languages, glossaries

I want to create a glossary and to name it "Glosario" (Spanish), but despite my attempts it continues to print "Glossary". MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\newcommand*{\glossaryname}{Glosario}
\usepackage[nonumberlist, toc]{glossaries}
\newcommand{\dictentry}[2]{%
\newglossaryentry{#1}{name=#1,description={#2}}%
  \glslink{#1}{}%
}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{CLR}{name=CLR,description={El ambiente de ejecución para el código gestionado}}
\newglossaryentry{.NET}{name=.NET,description={.Net es un framework para el desarrollo de aplicaciones de código gestionado desarrollado por Microsoft.}}

\begin{document}
El \gls{CLR} blablalbla

\newpage
\printglossary[style=altlist, toctitle=Glosario]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, replace

```
\newcommand*{\glossaryname}{Glosario}
```

with

```
\usepackage[spanish]{translator}
```

See pages 12-15 of the glossaries documentation for details.

EDIT: You may also omit `toctitle=Glosario` in the optional argument of `\printglossaries`.

Comment: Thank you! it works, i'm going to look more in deep the documentation.